# Outlook Signature delete images

Tags: email, outlook, signature

For my work, we stumbled upon a little problem. We have made a few mailboxes, and when a user send a mail to this mailbox, it will make a ticket in our ticketing system. 
That works fine! But our signature contains images, and our ticketing system takes these images as attachment. This is not what we want.

I tried making a transport rule to delete the signature, when we send it to one of these addresses, and looked it up on google. I saw on more sites that it was impossible to delete a signature with a transport rule.

I tried making a rule in outlook too, but i can't find anything.

Does somebody have the solution for this? I hope so! :)

Thanks in advance for thinking with me!

Comment: You could write a VBA macro which is called via [script rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875610/rule-based-email-handling-in-outlook-using-scripts/14876566#14876566) whenever a mail arrives. The macro could change the mail body and delete parts of it. Be aware that this could be complicated as mails can come in different formats (text, HTML, Rich-Text). There is also the risk that mail contents are deleted by mistake.

Comment: Compose messages in plain text format

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML body and find all the images. Delete attachments with the matching file name of the content-id property that matches the src attribute of the img tag.