# How to consume a webservice using excel?

Tags: web-services, excel, wsdl, consumption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call web service in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474936/call-web-service-in-excel)

Hi,

I have a wsdl-based webservice running on my intranet with some important organizational data that is constantly being updated.

I have excel reports generated from some software we have running here.

I would like to be able to consume the webservice using excel and to receive a specific dataset in one of my worksheets.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Thanks in advance,