# Creating an Excel plugin - what can be done?

Tags: web-services, excel, plugins

We may need to develop an Excel 'plugin' which collects data from the excel sheet, talks to a JSON webservice over HTTP and then populates another excel column.  Can this type of this be developed as some kind of Add On or plugin for Excel or would it have to be an external application which read and writes Excel files?  Does anyone have any useful developer Hello World type documents for Excel development?

Comment: your question is quite vague. Is this is possible? Yes. Want some hints? See the *related* part on the bottom right of this page (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474936/call-web-service-in-excel)). Want some links to tutos? [Really?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260(v=office.10).aspx